# Homotopy between two complex circles

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Im new into complex integration , and  I noticed that in order to  compute some complex integrals we need to give homotopies of two closed curves in order to apply the deformation theorem.

In  my case I want to give an explicit homotopy of two tangent circles (that happen to be closed curves) in order to use the deformation theorem.

The circles are the circle of center 1\2 and radius 1\2 and the cicle of center 1 and radius 1 (it obviously happens that the first circle is contained in the second  and both circles are tangent in zero). The intuition tells me this happens. But Im looking for the formal prove of this fact

So I can give a parametrization of these two circles by $\gamma_{0}(s)$= 1\2+$e^{is}$\2 and $\gamma_{1}(s)$= 1+$e^{is}$ where s$\in$ [0,2$\pi$]

The homotopy I want to explicit show is the one that :

H(s,0) = $\gamma_{0}(s)$ and H(s,1) = $\gamma_{1}(s)$

and the "closedness" is preserved that is H(a,t)=H(b,t) for every t $\in$ [0,1]

I aprecciate your help also if you can show me your line thought of how do you construct this homotopy it would be ver helpful since I have not found examples of these on internet nor books , not even past mathstackexchange questions :(

Answer (score 0):

$$H(s,t) = \left(\frac 12 + \frac t2\right) + \left( \frac 12 + \frac t2\right)e^{is}.$$

Has the property you want. The idea is that you move the center $1/2$ to $1$ along the real axis, while changing the radius in such a way that each circle $C_t$ still touch the origin.